# Prototypes, scope and Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

How do you bind the scope of Google to the fetch_page function? I need to be able to chain the functions together in promise-then chains.

```
Google.prototype.search = function(keyword){
    this.keyword = keyword || this.keyword;

    fetch_page().then(parse_page).then(function(){
        console.log('done');
    });
});

function fetch_page(){
    // I wants to access google's this.keyword
}

function parse_page(){
    // I also wants to access google's this.keyword
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `fetch_page.call(this).then(function (r) { console.log("done"); })`?

Comment: It's how to chain the second promise with the call.(this). Wouldn't that trigger the function rather than supply the scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function#call` can be used to call `fetch_page`, specifying the value to use as `this`: `fetch_page.call(this)`.

Then ES5's `Function#bind` or jQuery's `$.proxy` (I think you're using jQuery, from the promises you're using, but it's a guess — **Update**: And I was wrong, but I'll leave the info in case people using jQuery find the answer) to create a bound version of `parse_page` (that is, a function that, when called, will call `parse_page` with a specific `this` avlue).

`Function#bind`:

```
Google.prototype.search = function(keyword){
    this.keyword = keyword || this.keyword;

    fetch_page.call(this).then(parse_page.bind(this)).then(function(){
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Note that `Function#bind` is from ES5, so you'll want to check that all of the browsers you want have it. If not, it's one of the ES5 features that can be "shimmed" on older browsers; search for "ES5 shim" to find multiple options.

jQuery's `$.proxy`:

```
Google.prototype.search = function(keyword){
    this.keyword = keyword || this.keyword;

    fetch_page.call(this).then($.proxy(parse_page, this)).then(function(){
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Comment: I was using promised-io but .bind worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @lededje: Ah, quite so!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity I would go for:

```
fetch_page(keyword).then(function() {
    parse_page(keyword);
}).then(function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

and then add `keyword` to the parameter list of the two external functions.

Alternatively, just inline the two functions within `Google.prototype.search` so that they share the same scope.

A third approach is to [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the functions to explicitly set the context to be your `this` object:

```
var fetch = fetch_page.bind(this);
var parse = parse_page.bind(this);

fetch().then(parse).then(...);
```

Comment: I don't really want to bubble that though all the then functions afterward. Is there no other way to bind it?

Comment: This is also correct, but not as complete as TJs answer. +1 though.

Comment: @lededje I didn't want to assume that you're using jQuery

Comment: @Alnitak: I included ES5 first, then jQuery as an option. (And I was wrong, lededje isn't using jQuery, this is server side!) :-)

Answer (score -3):

Like this

```
var google = new Google(); // return the class instance

google.keyword // get the public class variable called keyword
```